# Which Hadoop version is used by Amazon (EMR)?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloudera, amazon-emr

I want to create a Hadoop job and to run it on EC2 Map Reduce.
Also I would like to run the job locally before uploading to EC2.

Which version/type of Hadoop should I have locally? Can I use Cloudera VM?
Which Hadoop version Amazon uses?

Comment: Haha I'm working on the same thing right now. I think .17 and cloudera has a dist of hadoop for ec2 specifically. Happy Hunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Elastic MapReduce supports Hadoop 0.18, 0.20, and 0.20.205 (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EnvironmentConfig_AMIVersion.html#ami-versions-supported).

You can specify which one you want to run. You can't select Cloudera; you could run raw instances on EC2 and set up your own Cloudera cluster I suppose.

Running locally is nothing to do with EMR; just set up a Hadoop cluster in pseudo-distributed mode for testing.

Comment: Found this answer from 2012, needs to be updated. It does point to helpful documentation which appears to state that they support 2.X and 3.X Hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Recently Amazon also added support for MapR M3 and M5:

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/mapr/

You can download MapR binaries at the following link:

http://www.mapr.com/products/download/download-mapr-on-premise

Shameless plug: At [Axemblr.com](http://axemblr.com) we are building an alternative to Amazon EMR based on Cloudera Manager target at multiple clouds. Drop us a line at hello@axemblr.com if you want early acceess.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EMR now uses Hadoop 2.4.0.  Updated information at:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ami-versions-supported.html